# ArcGIS map service layer not loading properly

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, map-service

I'm at a total loss. My initial problem was an issue with the layer not loading at all when the page was set to the full extent, despite having changed the Min/Max Scale settings generously when publishing the map service. I corrected this by rectifying the Scale settings in JavaScript:

```
landBaseLayer.on("load", function() { landBaseLayer.minScale = 0; landBaseLayer.maxScale = 0; });
```

I now have a problem with the layer not loading when entering the page. It loads when I zoom in, and the loaded subset will remain visible when I zoom back out, but everything around it will remain blank. What am I doing wrong? Sorry, I'm totally new to this. I'm using a cached map service, with a Max Record Count of 10,000 (the layer contains just over 7,000 points). The following is the entire code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
  on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Identify with Popup</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
</style>

<script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };</script>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/"></script>
<script>

  dojo.require("esri.map");
  dojo.require("esri.dijit.Popup");

  var map;
  var identifyTask, identifyParams;

  function init() {
    //setup the popup window 
    var popup = new esri.dijit.Popup({
      fillSymbol: new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2), new dojo.Color([255,255,0,0.25]))
    }, dojo.create("div"));

    map = new esri.Map("map", {
      basemap: "satellite",
      center: [-89.211, 39.977],
      zoom: 7,
      infoWindow: popup
    });

    dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", mapReady);

    var landBaseLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/WeekSample/MapServer",{opacity:.55});
    landBaseLayer.on("load", function() { landBaseLayer.minScale = 0; landBaseLayer.maxScale = 0; });
    map.addLayer(landBaseLayer);
  }

  function mapReady(map){
   dojo.connect(map,"onClick",executeIdentifyTask);
   //create identify tasks and setup parameters 
   identifyTask = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/WeekSample/MapServer");

   identifyParams = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
   identifyParams.tolerance = 3;
   identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
   identifyParams.layerIds = [0];
   identifyParams.layerOption = esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
   identifyParams.width  = map.width;
   identifyParams.height = map.height;
  }

  function executeIdentifyTask(evt) {
    identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
    identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;

    var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);

    deferred.addCallback(function(response) {     
      return dojo.map(response, function(result) {
        var feature = result.feature;
        feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
        if(result.layerName === 'Bloomingdale_Parcel'){
          //console.log(feature.attributes.PARCELID);
          console.log(feature.attributes.UNIQUEID);
          var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "<b>Unique ID:</b> <br/> ${UNIQUEID} <br/><br/> <b>Address:</b> <br/> ${PROP_LOC} <br/><br/> <b>Owner of record:</b> <br/> ${OWNER_NAME} <br/><br/> <b>Block ID:</b> <br/> ${BLOCK} <br/><br/> <b>Lot ID:</b> <br/> ${LOT}");
          feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        }
        //else if (result.layerName === 'Building Footprints'){
          //var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "Parcel ID: ${PARCELID}");
          //feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        //}
        return feature;
      });
    });


    map.infoWindow.setFeatures([ deferred ]);
    map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
  }

  dojo.ready(init);
</script>
```

Comment: try moving the map.addLayer inside the mapReady function as the first line

Answer (score 1):

I think the first issue is the old references to Dojo.  Rather than calling dijits using dojo.require() you should use:

```
require(["esri/map"], function(Map) { /* code goes here */ });
```

In the code above there is a combination of old (pre AMD) and current Dojo methods being used.  Although the code will still work this is not best practice. You mentioned "landbasedlayer" was a cached layer?  You are using **"ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer"** to call this when it should be **"ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer"** (see code below).

```
require(["esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer"], function(ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer) {   /* code goes here */ });
```

See if this addresses your issue, if not we can work from there.

Comment: This solution should fix the problem, I copied and pasted the code into the sandbox and did the following in my answer. In all fairness, I recommend choosing @jeremythamm's answer. Mine just clarifies the steps needed but doesn't offer anything else that he did not suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
      // dojo.require("esri.map");
      // dojo.require("esri.dijit.Popup");

  require ([

    "esri/map",
    "esri/dijit/Popup"
    ], function (
    Map,
    Popup
  ) {
```

...

```
  dojo.ready(init);
  });
```